# Conceptual/Notational question on conditional distributions and "given"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

So in the book I'm reading, I see the notations $f(x|\theta)$ being used to refer to population distributions, dependent on $\theta$ which are in a family. The author explains this as a notational convenience to keep track of the parameter $\theta$. My question is, is this the same as a conditional pdf? Can I write things like $$f(x|\theta)=f(x,\theta)/(f(\theta))$$. Also, what is the difference between $f(x|\theta)$ and just the marginal pdf of x, $f(x)$? I don't see the purpose of constantly conditioning on the parameter. This theme is continued for expectations as well. I know the distribution is dependent on its parameters, but why do we need to analyze the conditional distribution? Why would we take $\theta$ as given if its the very thing we are trying to find out about? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "notational convenience" the author really means "abuse of notation". It is not conditioning because $\theta$ is not random, and the display you wrote doesn't make sense for that reason (what would $f(\theta)$ be)? Many authors prefer something like $f_\theta(x), E_\theta(x)$ etc. What the author means by $f(x|\theta)$ is in fact the marginal density $f(x)$, using $\theta$ to index a family of distributions. Eg, you might write $f(x|\mu)=\phi(x-\mu)$ to refer to a normal density with mean $\mu$. Here the family is normal distributions with any mean, and $f(x|\theta),f_\theta(x),f(x|\mu),f_\mu(x)$ etc picks out one such normal distribution. This response should all be qualified by saying that in a bayesian framework, where $\theta$ is in fact a random variable, $f(x|\theta)$ would not be an abuse of notation, and bayes rule would apply.

Comment: Okay. So, outside of Bayesian, every time I see something like $E[x|\theta]$  I am really just finding $\int_{X}xf(x)dx$ Where f(x) is the pdf of x (plugging in $\theta$ for the parameter as needed of course) I don't need to compute a conditional pdf, then take a conditional expected value, correct? I would need the thing Im conditioning on to be a random variable for $E[X|Y]=\int_{X}xf(X|Y)dx$ to make sense?

Comment: Yes to the first question, although you can see why the authors wouldn't just write $\int x f(x) dx$ if $f(x)$ is parametrized by $\theta$. Yes to the second--you condition on a random variable--although the conditional expectation $E[X|Y]$ usually refers to a somewhat more general concept than what you wrote on the rhs, which will hold only in special cases that $f(X|Y)$ is available.